# How to edit jasper file?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am editing .jasper file using report tool. I am changing the alignment for parameter left to centre then i save that file. it generates the "jrxml" file also. in my Java code I can pass the .jasper location to print some items. but my changes not affect and the old design remains same..

Help me , How can I edit and save .jasper???

public static JasperPrint createRefundPrint(Ticket ticket, HashMap map) throws Exception {
        final String FILE_RECEIPT_REPORT = "/com/floreantpos/report/template/RefundReceipt.jasper";

```
    TicketDataSource dataSource = new TicketDataSource(ticket);
    return createJasperPrint(FILE_RECEIPT_REPORT, map, new JRTableModelDataSource(dataSource));
}
```

Comment: delete the old jasper file from your location and compile the jasperReport **(.jrxml file)** in IReport tool.. you will get the updated jasper file

Answer (score 1):

if you use a IReport for editing your .jrxml reports, you should just press the "Preview" button. Then the .jasper report file will be generated automatically in folder that contains the .jrxml file

Answer (score 0):

To edit jasper report, you make your changes in the JRXML file. Once you build or compile your report it will generate a .jasper file which is used in your java code.

Answer (score 0):

you try make dynamic report. 
You do not have a location problem when you generate your own report.
Example;

```
public JasperDesign createDesign() throws JRException {
    JasperDesign jasperDesign = new JasperDesign();
    jasperDesign.setName("sampleDynamicJasperDesign");
    jasperDesign.setPageWidth(595); // page width
    jasperDesign.setPageHeight(842); // page height
    jasperDesign.setColumnWidth(515);   // column width of page
    jasperDesign.setColumnSpacing(0);
    jasperDesign.setLeftMargin(40);
    jasperDesign.setRightMargin(40);
    jasperDesign.setTopMargin(20);
    jasperDesign.setBottomMargin(20);

    JRDesignExpression expression = new JRDesignExpression();

    //Set style of page.
    JRDesignStyle normalStyle = new JRDesignStyle();
    normalStyle.setName("Sans_Normal");
    normalStyle.setDefault(true);
    normalStyle.setFontName("DejaVu Sans");
    normalStyle.setFontSize(12);
    normalStyle.setPdfFontName("Helvetica");
    normalStyle.setPdfEncoding("Cp1252");
    normalStyle.setPdfEmbedded(false);
    jasperDesign.addStyle(normalStyle);


    /*
    * Generate field dynamically
    * */

    JRDesignField field = new JRDesignField();
    field.setName("firstName");
    field.setValueClass(String.class);
    jasperDesign.addField(field);

    field = new JRDesignField();
    field.setName("lastName");  // set name for field.
    field.setValueClass(String.class);  // set class for field. Its always depends upon data type which we want to get in this field.
    jasperDesign.addField(field);   // Added field in design.

    field = new JRDesignField();
    field.setName("age");
    field.setValueClass(Integer.class);
    jasperDesign.addField(field);

    JRDesignBand band = new JRDesignBand();

    //Title Band
    band = new JRDesignBand();
    band.setHeight(30);


    JRDesignStaticText staticText = new JRDesignStaticText();
    staticText.setText("Person's Specification");
    staticText.setX(0);
    staticText.setY(0);
    staticText.setHeight(20);
    staticText.setWidth(515);
    staticText.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignEnum.CENTER);
    band.addElement(staticText);
    jasperDesign.setTitle(band);


    band = new JRDesignBand(); // New band
    band.setHeight(20); // Set band height

    /*Create text field dynamically*/
    JRDesignTextField textField = new JRDesignTextField();
    textField.setX(0);  // x position of text field.
    textField.setY(0);  // y position of text field.
    textField.setWidth(160);    // set width of text field.
    textField.setHeight(20);    // set height of text field.
    JRDesignExpression jrExpression = new JRDesignExpression(); // new instanse of expression. We need create new instance always when need to set expression.
    jrExpression.setText(""" + "First Name: " + """ + "+" + "$F{firstName}"); //  Added String before field in expression.
    textField.setExpression(jrExpression);  // set expression value in textfield.
    band.addElement(textField); // Added element in textfield.

    textField = new JRDesignTextField();
    textField.setX(160);
    textField.setY(0);
    textField.setWidth(160);
    textField.setHeight(20);
    jrExpression = new JRDesignExpression();
    jrExpression.setText("$F{lastName}" + "+" + """ + " :Last Name" + """); // Added string after field value
    textField.setExpression(jrExpression);
    band.addElement(textField);

    textField = new JRDesignTextField();
    textField.setX(320);
    textField.setY(0);
    textField.setWidth(160);
    textField.setHeight(20);
    jrExpression = new JRDesignExpression();
    String age = """ + "<font>" + """ + "+" + """ + "Age is: " + """ + "+" + """ + "</font><font>" + """ + "+" + "$F{age}" + "+" + """ + "</font>" + """;  // added html in text field with different color.
    jrExpression.setText(age);
    textField.setExpression(jrExpression);
    textField.setMarkup("html"); // By Default markup is none, We need to set it as html if we set expression as html.
    band.addElement(textField);
    ((JRDesignSection) jasperDesign.getDetailSection()).addBand(band);


    return jasperDesign;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compile a .jrxml in Project Explorer window of Jaspersoft Studio. For that first find your .jrxml report and rightclick on it. In context menu choose 'Compile report'. Then you get compiled .jasper report.